# cin.getline function does not wait for me to input the line in c++

Tags: c++

The code is simple. Yet, I'm confused about cin.getline() function. From my understanding of the following code, after the prompt "what is the message today?", the computer would wait for me to give an input. Yet, it is not like this.

cin.getline() is used to read unformatted string (set of characters) from the standard input device (keyboard). This function reads complete string until a give delimiter or null match.

```
// C-string.cpp : using C strings //
-----------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>   // include header file cstring 

using namespace std; 
char header[] = "\n      *** C Strings ****** \n\n"; 
int main() 
{ 
    char hello[30] = "Hello", name[20], message[80];
    cout << header << "Your first name: ";
    cin >> setw(20) >> name;   
    strcat(hello, name);   
    cout << hello << endl;   
    cin.sync();   
    cout << "\n what is the message today?" << endl;   
    cin.getline(message, 80);   
    if (strlen(message)>0)   
    { 
        for (int i=0; message[i]!= '\0'; ++i)
            cout << message[i] << ' ';
        cout << endl; 
    }   
    return 0; 
}
```

output:

```
dev$:./a.out

      *** C Strings ****** 

Your first name: l Hellol

what is the message today? dev$:
```

Comment: Your code is missing a `main` function.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::getline` with character arrays.  You need to limit the input so your arrays don't overflow.

Comment: When I try to compile your example, my IDE is complaining about missing variable declarations.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it actually does have a `main` function, but due to the terrible indentation/whitespace mangling, half of the code is a comment on the `#include <cstring>` line.